# Call to a member function on boolean (a la práctica)

Tags: php, pdo

Me da el error del asunto en una página que estoy creando en PHP que, curiosamente, estoy copiando de una anterior en el mismo sitio y que funciona perfectamente. Primero pongo la que me da error y, a continuación, la que funciona correctamente:

A no ser por un error ortográfico, diría que sí hay un campo llamado AppId. Adjunto DDL.

```js
CREATE TABLE Apps (
    IdApp                    INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                         UNIQUE
                                         NOT NULL,
    NombreApp                STRING (50) UNIQUE,
    IdPlataforma             INTEGER     REFERENCES Plataformas (IdPlataforma) 
                                         NOT NULL,
    IdDesarrollador          INTEGER     REFERENCES Desarrolladores (IdDesarrollador),
    DescApp                  TEXT        UNIQUE
                                         NOT NULL,
    IdCategoriaAppStore      INTEGER     REFERENCES CategoriasAppStore (IdCategoria),
    IdCategoriaSDP           INTEGER     REFERENCES CategoriasSDP (IdCategoriaSDP),
    SoporteAppleWatch        BOOLEAN,
    VersionApp               STRING (10),
    DePago                   BOOLEAN,
    ProbadoEnIphone          BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnIpad            BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnIpodTouch       BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnMacMini         BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnMacBook                     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnImac            BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnAppleWatch      BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    ProbadoEnAppleTV         BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    VersionOS                STRING (10),
    ComentariosAccesibilidad TEXT,
    IdCoVO                   INTEGER     REFERENCES ComportamientoVO (IdCoVO),
    IdEtiquetadoBotones      INTEGER     REFERENCES EtiquetadoBotones (IdEtBotones),
    IdUsabilidad             INTEGER     REFERENCES Usabilidad (IdUsabilidad) 
                                         NOT NULL,
    OtrosComentarios         TEXT,
    EnlaceAppStore           STRING (75) UNIQUE
                                         NOT NULL,
    IdiomaES                 BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaCAT                BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaGAL                BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaEUS                BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaFR                 BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaEN                 BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaDE                 BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaIT                 BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    IdiomaMULTI              BOOLEAN     DEFAULT (0),
    AppId                    TEXT (15)   UNIQUE,
    EnlaceAfiliado           TEXT (250)  UNIQUE );
```

LISTADO APP - IDS

> Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   fetchAll() on boolean in
>   /home/sucdepoma/new.sucdepoma.org/triplea/lista_appids.php:12 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/sucdepoma/new.sucdepoma.org/triplea/lista_appids.php on line 12

```
<?php

include("cmmns.php");

printHtmlHeader("LISTADO DE APP - IDS");
$db = new PDO ("sqlite:triplea.sqlite3");
$sql = "
     SELECT AppId
     FROM Apps
     ";
$query = $db->query ($sql);
$apps = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($apps as $app)
{
    extract($app);
    print ("<li>$NombreApp</li>");
}
printHtmlFooter ();
?>
```

LISTADO_APPS
Funciona correctamente

```
<?php

include("cmmns.php");

printHtmlHeader("LISTADO DE APPS");
$db = new PDO ("sqlite:triplea.sqlite3");
$sql = "
     SELECT NombreApp
     FROM Apps
     ORDER BY NombreApp
 ";
$query = $db->query ($sql);
$apps = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($apps as $app)
{
    extract($app);
    print ("<li>$NombreApp</li>");
}
printHtmlFooter ();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Realmente la tabla `Apps` tiene una columna llamada **`AppId`**? ¿La ejecución de esta consulta directamente en el DBMS : `SELECT AppId FROM Apps` genera algún resultado?

Comment: Aquí tienes el DDL de la tabla Apps:

Comment: @gbianchi hay un AppId al final de la tabla

Comment: Solo como prueba, podes cambiar el query en LISTADO_APPS solo para saber que realmente no tenes problemas con el query?